# 'U' (Generic Type) is not convertible to 'Dictionary<Key, Value>'

Tags: generics, swift, dictionary

I'm trying to write a function that can transform the input regardless of object types.

Example use case could be something like:

```
// Example 1, Strings
In: ("foo", "bar")
Out: "foobar"

// Example 2, Integers
In: (5, 10)
Out: 15

// Example 3, Mixed (String, Array)
In: ("baz", ["foo", "bar"])
Out: ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
```

The way I've approached the problem was by creating a function that accepts generic types, and it runs them through a switch to detect which type they are, then processes them accordingly.

The function looks something like this

```
func process<T:Hashable,U> (lhs: T, rhs: U) -> U {
    switch _stdlib_getTypeName(right) {
    case "_TtSS": // string
        // process
    case "_TtSa": // array
        // process
    case "_TtVSs10Dictionary": // dictionary
        // process
    default:
        println(_stdlib_getTypeName(rhs))
    return rhs
}
```

Now, none of the code above pertains to my question, but I decided to include it for analysis, as maybe I'm not approaching my problem the correct way. I read somewhere that "if you're checking the type of a generic type, you shouldn't be using generic types.". Which sounds pretty accurate.

I've been wondering if maybe it's better to approach this with a dictionary with the key set as a type (_TtSS for String) and a function as it's value. Then just running the appropriate function for the generic variable by using `functions[_stdlib_getTypeName(right)]()`. However, this is still type checking the generic type.

**So now I've arrived at the original question**, in my `case`s for strings and arrays, I'm able to access class-specific functions by using `(right as String)`or `(right as Array)`. However, when I try to run `(right as Dictionary)`, I'm greeted with an error, `error: 'U' is not convertible to 'Dictionary<Key, Value>'`

The input when the error is produced was `["foo": "bar", "baz": "qux"]`. The error persisted regardless if the key was an `Int` or `String`.

Any idea what would be causing this?

Comment: Please write a function which can be executed in a playground.  Your function is neither syntactically correct (no executable statements in switch cases, missing }} at end), nor type correct (println instead of return), nor compilable - use of rhs instead of right.

Comment: Your title conflicts with the body - is the error in U or T

Comment: @AlexBrown my apologies. Serves me right for writing dummy code for my question and skipping over those points while proof reading. My actual code uses lhs and rhs for the variables, as it's an infix. Fixed the typos and errors.

Comment: You might be a lot happier calling `_stdlib_getDemangledTypeName`

Comment: @matt you are my savior! I was looking for such a function, the closest I fount was `_stdlib_getTypeName`. These functions should really be better documented.

Comment: Can you show the actual code you haves problem with?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than building a switch statement, you can build a specialised instance for each pair of types you have a real implementation for.

It's important to work out if you need a base (default case) or not, and what it should do.   Your options are:

- Have the base case return `nil!` - then everything else must be explicitly unwrapped, too.  This will cause the program to assert at runtime if it fails.  While this is what I chose below, it's not necessarily the best path.
- Have the base case return `nil?` - then everything else must be manually unwrapped, too.  This will cause the compiler to insist the programmer handles the nil case.
- Elide the base case - the compiler will catch missing cases at build time, but you won't be able to use the `process` function inside other generics.
- Have the base case fatalError at runtime
- Have the base case just return `lhs` without appending
- Have a special base case for each `lhs` where `rhs` is not explicitly supported.
- have the base case simply return `lhs`

If you have a set of classes whose implementation is basically the same, we can shortcut this using a protocol.  The examples for `Double`, `String` and `Array` use this strategy.

```
// default case.  Can be elided, return nil, or fatalError.  I'm returning nil.
func process<T,U>(var lhs:T,rhs:U) -> T! {
    return nil // nil! will cause consuming code to assert unless they explicitly check
}

// explicit case for array + member
func process<T>(var lhs:[T],rhs:T) -> [T]! {
    lhs.append(rhs)
    return lhs
}

// explicit case for dictionary + tuple
func process<K:Hashable,V>(var lhs:[K:V],rhs:(K,V)) -> [K:V] {
    lhs[rhs.0] = rhs.1
    return lhs
}

protocol AAA {
    func +(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
}

// case to handle the + protocol variant
func process<T:AAA>(lhs:T,rhs:T) -> T! {
    return lhs + rhs
}

// indicate already conforming classes
extension Double:AAA {}
extension Int:AAA {}
extension Array:AAA {}
extension String:AAA {}    

process("a", "b")     // -> "ab"
process(["a"], "b")   // -> ["a","b"]
process(["a"], ["b"]) // -> ["a","b"]
process(1,3)         // -> 4
process(1.0,3.0)     // nil - no implementation
process(NSDate(),"grr") //  nil - no implementation
process(["a":1],("b",2))  // ["a":1,"b":2]
```

---

### Operators

If you want to have an infix operator instead of a function (as suggested in your comments, simply add the operator declaration:

```
infix operator +++ {}
```

Then replace all instances of `process` with the operator, e.g. `+++`, and then call it as follows:

```
   [1,2,3] +++ 1
   [1,2,3] +++ [4]
   1 +++ 9
```

etc.

Comment: So what happens with a dictionary?

Comment: I don't know what semantics you want exactly.  Do you want `<K:Hashable,V>([K:V], (K,V)) -> [K,V])`, or `<K:Hashable,V>([K:V], [K:V]) -> [K,V]` or something else?

Comment: Something about this suggestion is making my skin crawl. I think it's how repetitive it seems, conflicting with my DRY standards.

Comment: @mediachicken Well this is how Swift works. Look at how + is implemented in the header - about 20 different times, one for each kind of parameter. That is what you do - you use overloading and generic functions. Get over it.

Comment: Alright, I can accept that. Coming from a python background, I'm used to making everything as dynamic as possible. I'll continue implementing it this way. Thanks!

Comment: For Objective-C types, you could in fact create a dynamic declaration for NSObject which searches for suitably named selectors, although it might be prone to misfires on other uses of that selector.

Comment: While it does appear there is a pattern, there isn't in fact all that much repetition; `+(Int,Int)` is not an overload of some base `+`, it's a completely different beast from `+(Float,Float)`.

Answer (score 0):

### Switch approach

In my other answer I laid out the case for generics, but there is another approach, using [switch downcasting](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH22-ID342):

Here we are interested in expressing the output of combining two types.

A switch statement can handle the type matching for us:

```
func process2<T:Any,U:Any>(var _lhs: T, _rhs: U) -> T {

    switch (_lhs, _rhs) {
    case (var lhs as String, let rhs as String): // string
        return lhs + rhs as T
    case (var lhs as Array<U>, let rhs): // array
        lhs.append(rhs)
        return lhs as T
    case let (lhs as Double, rhs as Double):
        return lhs + rhs as T
    case let (lhs as Int, rhs as Int):
        return lhs + rhs as T
    default:
        println("default case")
        return _lhs
    }
}
```

So let's use this:

```
process2(["foo"],"bar") // ["foo","bar"]
process2(1.0,2.0)       // 3.0
process2("a","b")       // "ab"
process2(1,2)           // 3
```

I haven't yet worked out how to do Array+Array or Dictionary+anything

Comment: The templating in the above example is probably not necessary, except for the fact that it allows (1) the Array case to work smoothly, and (2) the return type to be something other than Any.

Comment: This is similar enough to my original code that I'd like to think I was heading in the right direction. Well it may not be the official way to do it, do you not agree that it's a pretty elegant solution? Although I see your having the same issues with the dictionaries. I'm going to start plugging away at this code to see if I can make anything work.

Comment: I don't think its possible to unpack a generic's types in a switch statement right now, so you are better off with my other Answer.

Comment: However as a general pattern this is an improvement over the mangled name decoding you originally suggested.